# jQuery undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am new to jQuery and whilst working with jQuery Datatables I am coming across this problem which I believe is simple but I cannot figure it out. Handlers `.iframe`, `.iframe2` and `.iframe3` work fine, the problem is `.iframe4`.

I am managing to get the value of `data[0]` in `.iframe`, `.iframe2` and `.iframe3` but I cannot get to display its value in `.iframe4`. For now I simply need to display the value of `data[0]` in `.iframe4` but I am getting a JS error saying that the value is undefined. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        //  bPaginate: false,
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<input type='image' src='delete.png' id='button' >"
        },
        {
            "targets": -2,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<input type='image' src='edit.png' id='button' >"
        },
        {
            "targets": -3,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<input type ='image' src='edit.png' id='button' >"
        },
        {
            "targets": -4,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": " "
        }
        ],
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
    } );
        $('#example tbody').ready(function(){
           var data = table.row( $(this).closest('tr') ).data();
           $(".iframe4").ready(function()
           {
               $(".iframe4").text(data[0]);
           });
       });
        $('#example tbody').on('click', 'input', function(){
         var data = table.row( $(this).closest('tr') ).data();
         $(".iframe").colorbox({maxWidth:'95%', maxHeight:'95%', href:"session_edit.php?ID="+data[0]});
         $(".iframe3").colorbox({href:"delete.php?ID="+data[0]});
     });
        $('#example tbody').on('click', 'input', function(){
           var data = table.row( $(this).closest('tr') ).data();
           $(".iframe2").ready(function()
            {window.location.replace("record_dt.php?ID="+data[0])});
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is `.iframe4`? What is undefined - `data[0]` or `.iframe4`? What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code. Most likely this is what you wanted to do instead:

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'input', function () {
    var data = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
    $(".iframe4").ready(function () {
        $(".iframe4").text(data[0]);
    });
});
```

However it's bad choice to attach event handler in click event without first detaching it. I believe you can use the code below instead.

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'input', function () {
    var data = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
    $(".iframe4").text(data[0]);
});
```

It applies to your other click handlers as well.

Comment: sorry but it's not working as well. All I need is to display the value of data[0]